# Why can't I remove the event listener in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom-events

While I know, that this question has been asked numerous time, the usual answer is *"you're passing a copy, not the original"*. Unless I'm understanding something wrong, this is not the problem in my case.

I made a Modal in React using the following code:

```
const Modal: React.StatelessComponent<Props> = 
({ isOpen, closeModal, closeOnClick = true, style, children }: Props) => {

  const closeOnEsc: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      closeModal();
    }
  };

  if (isOpen) {
    document.body.classList.add('freezeScroll');
    window.addEventListener('keyup', closeOnEsc, { once: true });
    return (
      <div className={styles.modal} onClick={closeOnClick ? closeModal : undefined} >
        <div className={`${styles.modalContent} ${closeOnClick ? styles.clickable : undefined} ${style}`} >
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  document.body.classList.remove('freezeScroll');
  window.removeEventListener('keyup', closeOnEsc, { once: true });
  return null;
};
```

I've only added the `{once: true}` option, because I can't remove it otherwise.
`window.removeEventListener` does get called once the modal is closed, but it doesn't remove the event listener.
Can anyone help me figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't manually bind listeners in a SFC personally. If you really want to though, I would just make the callback remove the listener.

In your `closeOnEsc` callback, add `window.removeEventListener('keyup', closeOnEsc);`

The problem with this, if the component is unmounted without the callback being invoked, then you have a small memory leak.

I would use a class component, and ensure the listener is also removed in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: It does work with a class component, and I like your way better than mine - so thanks for that, first of all.  

But I would still like to find out why it doesn't remove the listener in the SFC.

Comment: Change the trigger event to `keydown` and it should work. Works in all my test cases.

Comment: keydown doesn't work in my case either, so the problem seems to be somewhere else. But since you gave me a working alternative I'm gonna mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not attach event listener directly inside render. These are not idempotent side effects and it will cause memory leak. On each render (even if it is not commited to DOM), you are assigning event listeners After your modal is closed, you remove only last one. Right way to do it would be either using `useEffect` (or `useLayoutEffect` hook), or converting your component into class and using lifecycle methods.

Here is annotated example with hooks:

```js
const Modal: React.StatelessComponent<Props> = ({
  isOpen,
  closeModal,
  closeOnClick = true,
  style,
  children,
}: Props) => {
  useEffect(
    function () {
      // we don't need to add listener when modal is closed
      if (!isOpen) return;
      // we are closuring function to properly remove event listener later
      const closeOnEsc: (e: KeyboardEvent) => void = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
          closeModal();
        }
      };
      window.addEventListener("keyup", closeOnEsc);
      // We return cleanup function that will be executed either before effect will be fired again,
      // or when componen will be unmounted
      return () => {
        // since we closured function, we will definitely remove listener
        window.removeEventListener("keyup", closeOnEsc);
      };
    },
    [isOpen]
  );

  useEffect(
    function () {
      // it is very tricky with setting class on body, since we theoretically can have multiple open modals simultaneously
      // if one of this model will be closed, it will remove class from body.
      // This is not particularly good solution - it is better to have some centralized place to set this class.
      // This is why I moved it into separate effect
      if (isOpen) {
        document.body.classList.add("freezeScroll");
      } else {
        document.body.classList.remove("freezeScroll");
      }
      // just in case if modal would be unmounted, we reset body
      return () => {
        document.body.classList.remove("freezeScroll");
      };
    },
    [isOpen]
  );

  if (isOpen) {
    return (
      <div
        className={styles.modal}
        onClick={closeOnClick ? closeModal : undefined}
      >
        <div
          className={`${styles.modalContent} ${
            closeOnClick ? styles.clickable : undefined
          } ${style}`}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

Again. It is very important that render method of classes and function components don't have any side effects that are not idempotent. Idempotence in this case means that if we call some side effect multiple times, it will not change the outcome. This is why you can call `console.log` from render - it is idempotent, at least from our perspective. Same with react hooks. You can (and should!) call them on each render without messing up react internal state. Attaching new event listener to DOM or window is not idempotent, since on each render you attach new event listener without clearing previous one.

Technically, you can first remove event listener, and then attach new without `useEffect`, but in this case you will have to preserve listener identity (reference) between renders somehow, or remove all keyup events from window at once. Former is hard to do (you are creating new function on every render), and latter can interfere with other parts of your program.